# Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function and $A \subseteq Y$ and $B \subseteq Y$. Show that $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function and $A \subseteq Y$ and $B \subseteq Y$. Show that $A \subseteq f^{−1}(f(A))$.

My defintion of inverse image is: Let $f: A \to B$ be a function and $Y \subseteq B$.

The inverse image of $Y$ is the set $f^{-1}(Y) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in Y\}$

I think I have to take an $a\in A$ and show this $a$ also is inside $f^{-1}(f(A))$. But how can I do it?

Comment: Remember that we have that $a\in f^{-1}(f(a))$ (why? think about the definition of inverse image!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \in A$, then *by definition* $f(a) \in f(A)$. And so *by definition* $a \in f^{-1}(f(A))$, (applying the definition of $f^{-1}(B)$ to $B=f(A)$), because its image is in $f(A)$. There's no more to it than that.

Similarly $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B$ also holds by the definitions: $y \in f(f^{-1}(B))$ iff $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in f^{-1}(B)$. But $x \in f^{-1}(B)$ means exactly that $f(x)\in B$ so $y=f(x) \in B$ and as $y$ was arbitrary the inclusion holds.